# Save Properties.Settings.Default items to list, change the values and then save it to the file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, settings

In my Settings.settings file I have 10 bool items, I am trying to save them all to the list, then iterate through them, change their values and then save it back to the settings file but it doesn't work.

Here is short example:

```
    public List<bool> list = new List<bool>();

    list.Add(Properties.Settings.Default.Item0);
    list.Add(Properties.Settings.Default.Item1);
    list.Add(Properties.Settings.Default.Item2);
    list.Add(Properties.Settings.Default.Item3);
    list.Add(Properties.Settings.Default.Item4);
    // ... up to 10
```

Then I am trying to iterator through them:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (listBox1.GetSelected(i))
            {
                list[i] = true;
            }
            else
            {
                list[i] = false;
            }
        }

        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();  // it sets list items properly but it doesn't actually save it to the user settings file
```

so if I'll do something like this:

```
            if (listBox1.GetSelected(0))
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.Item0 = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.Item0 = false;
            }

            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

it will save it and next time I am opening my app I'll get the correct saved values,
but I don't want to have inefficiency with 10 if statements for each item

Comment: you can change your for loop innards to list[i]=listBox1.GetSelected(i)

Comment: and in the same manner, the last bit to Properties.Settings.Default.Item0 = listBox1.GetSelected(0);

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't answer my question. The question is how to save those values to settings file while using it with the list.

Comment: wasn't trying to answer the question, just give a tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access the settings by name, like so.

```
Settings.Default["Item1"];
```

Since you have the naming convention Item + Incrementing Number in your for loop you could do this,

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    Settings.Default["Item" + i.ToString()] = listBox1.GetSelected(i);
}
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```